# how to set different background shape when hover on image?

Tags: html, css

I have created three images in column, and i set

```
column-count: 3;
```

And i set border-width for those three images. Now i need to know about hover state.

Html:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <h1 class="content-title">
     <span>Popular</span>
  </h1>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="popular">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/bq6aahcpn/Book_ll_4.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="caption"><a href="olymbic.html"><h2>Saina nehwal first match</h2><p>fasdfjaksdksdfh skdfk</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="popular">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/bq6aahcpn/Book_ll_4.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="caption"><a href="#"><h2>Saina nehwal first match</h2><p>fasdfjaksdksdfh skdfk</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="popular">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/bq6aahcpn/Book_ll_4.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="caption"><a href="#"><h2>Saina nehwal first match</h2><p>fasdfjaksdksdfh skdfk</p></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When i hover an image, It need to show like this

[image]

And here is my worked jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6g7v899q/

I need something like this [can you please refer this site gatesnotes.com in reading post part?.. I need like this.. ]

May i know, how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be possible with the `width` and `color` of the borders on the box, the page you refer has this styles:

```
.hpunit .hpimgrel .hpbook:hover .gbox {
   border-left: 59px solid #ddd;
   border-right: 59px solid #ddd;
}
```

In your code can be like this:

```css
.popular {
  display:inline-block;
  border:40px solid #eee;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.popular:hover {
  border-left:40px solid gray;
  border-right:40px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <h1 class="content-title">
     <span>Popular</span>
  </h1>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="popular">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/bq6aahcpn/Book_ll_4.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="caption"><a href="olymbic.html"><h2>Saina nehwal first match</h2><p>fasdfjaksdksdfh skdfk</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="popular">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/bq6aahcpn/Book_ll_4.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="caption"><a href="#"><h2>Saina nehwal first match</h2><p>fasdfjaksdksdfh skdfk</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="popular">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/bq6aahcpn/Book_ll_4.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="caption"><a href="#"><h2>Saina nehwal first match</h2><p>fasdfjaksdksdfh skdfk</p></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Glad to help U @selva